# Can I refresh a javascript UWP app on windows 10?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10

I don't want to stop my app, and run it when I make code changes. I want my app to always run and I simply want to have a refresh button, so when I change my code I can simply refresh the window, ie ZERO wait time. kind of like they have a refresh button in the browser.

Is this possible in windows 10 / javascript development?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-uwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean make code changes under debug mode. If in that case, you can make changes to your code while you're debugging, and then refresh a Store app using JavaScript by choosing the **Refresh Windows app** button on the Debug toolbar. Choosing this button reloads the app without stopping and restarting the debugger. Details please reference [Refresh an app (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj126108.aspx).

In Visual Studio 2017, you can find the button looks like this: [image].

If you don't mean under debug mode, by testing on my side, re-deploy will auto close the currently running app to force restart.